# Animate ImageView when sliding to fill width

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation

I am trying to achieve an animation like this one [now playing page](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/1128533/screenshots/2657184/__________1.gif)

where after sliding up, the album art stretches to fill the width. What is the most efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the same view, I would have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html which allows you to transition between two layouts in the same `Activity` or `Fragment`.

If you're adding a new fragment, you will want to override the transition, with something like :

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_slide_up, R.animator.fragment_slide_down)
```

Finally if you're switching activities, you will want to have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html (Part 3 about activity transitions and shared elements)